# Function Pointers within structures in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, structure

```
typedef struct Item{

  int i;
  int j;    
  void (*fooprint)(item*);

}item;

void fooprint(item *it){
  printf("%d\n",it.i);
}


int main(){

  item myitem;
  myitem.i=10;
  myitem.j=20;
  myitem.fooprint = fooprint;

  myitem.fooprint(&myitem);
  return 0;
}
```

This code gives a error at void (*footprint)(item*). "The error is expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token ". Am I missing something ? When I do the same without using pointer to the structure is works. Example : void (*footprint)(item)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type `item` is not known yet when you use it. You can solve that with a forward declaration.

```
typedef struct Item item;
struct Item {
    int i;
    int j;
    void (*fooprint)(item*);
};
```

Another possibility is not to use the `typedef` to define members:

```
typedef struct Item {
    int i;
    int j;
    void (*fooprint)(struct Item *);
} item;
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, and it through me off when he said it works when he leaves the asterisk off.

Comment: Now, the warning I have is :"useless storage class specifier in empty declaration"

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't recognise `item` as a type (because it's not defined yet). Your compiler thinks here that it is a storage declaration (usually `auto`, `register`, ...) for an empty type. But that's just an implementation detail of your compiler. My compiler (clang) outputs `error: a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why you're getting the particular error you are -- the error I got was "error: unknown type name ‘item’". This is because the typedef has not "happened" yet, and C doesn't know what the type `item` refers to. Use `struct Item` in place of `item` there.

(Also, `it.i` in the `printf` should be `it->i`).