# Why can't I initialize my array of structures containing function pointers in C?

Tags: c, structure, function-pointers, array-initialization

**my_functions.h**

```
void * f1 (int * param);
void * f2 (int * param);
void * f3 (int * param);
void b1(int * param);
void b2(int * param);
void b3(int * param);
```

**my_prog.c**

```
#include <my_functions.h>

// Typedef my function pointers
typedef void * (*foo)(int*);
typedef void (*bar)(int*);

// Declare the structure that will contain function pointers
typedef struct _my_struct
{
    int tag;
    foo f;
    bar b;
}my_struct;

// Declare and initialize the array of my_struct
my_struct array[] =
{
    {1, f1, b1},
    {2, f2, b2},
    {3, f3, b3}
};
```

Compiler says:

> warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type

I looked at:

- [Function Pointers within structures in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19897047/3194340)
- [Initializing a function pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23269710/3194340)
- [How to initialize array of pointers to functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5192174/3194340)

But I still can't see what I missed...
For me, all the types and the functions are known by the time I try to initialize my array.
Can't the init be done outside a function ?

**[EDIT]** I am on Linux, using an embedded version for arm of GCC 4.9.

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: For me too. At which line do you get the error ? Which compiler/platform/OS are you using ?

Comment: I am reviewing my code as I simplified it in my post... I might have missed something. I get the warning at all the closing braces of the `{x,fx,bx}`

Comment: And does your simplified code compile w/o warnings ?

Comment: Actually it doesn't throw any warning. The compiler I use is to blame, cf my own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so my code works just fine on my PC, it is actually the arm-gcc compiler that I use for my embedded target that throw this error because it seems it can't recognize the type of the function pointers without an explicit cast:

Here is the fix:

```
my_struct array[] =
{
    {1, (foo)f1, (bar)b1},
    {2, (foo)f2, (bar)b2},
    {3, (foo)f3, (bar)b3}
};
```